# Verify Id Token In Android Backend Call to Python

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

As explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html), I am trying to verify a token that is passed, by an Android app, to a server running python3.

I want to verify the passed token.  The trouble is that I am running python3 on the server which is not supported by the google-api-python-client library.  I found the following workaround, using the pyjwt and requests libraries, from this [site](http://www.fergalmoran.com/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android-using-python/):

```
import json
import jwt
import requests

GOOGLE_CERTS_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'


class GoogleIdToken(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._certs = {}
        self._token = {}

    def getCerts(self):
        cert = requests.get(GOOGLE_CERTS_URI)
        if cert.status_code == 200:
            return json.loads(cert.content)

    def isValid(self, token, audience, clientId=None):
        self._certs = self.getCerts()
        for key in self._certs:
            try:
                token = jwt.decode(token, key=self._certs[key], verify=False)
                if 'email' in token and 'aud' in token:
                    if token['aud'] == audience and (clientId == token['cid'] if clientId is not None else True):
                        self._token = token
                        return True
            except Exception, e:
                print("Error decoding: %s" % e.message)
        return False
```

My two questions are:

1. Does anyone know of a different and/or better existing solution that works in python3?
2. Is the solution above complete?

Comment: Have you found a better solution?

Comment: No, I never did find a good solution.

Comment: Does this still work for you or has Google changed anything? Looking for a native / own implementation myself. The Google libraries are horribly bloated.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger They are... I've since switched to firebase auth using firebase ui. Much much easier: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it in the meantime and realized, there's no need for pyjwt if you use `verify=False`. Also the certificate pulling has no function here. Basically, you can decode the JWT from Google using Python's base64 decoder. You can then verify everything manually, except the signature - for which the certificates are needed. And validating the signature is extremely complex without third party libs. So, your recommendation is certainly of great help.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of googling around and some trial and error, this is how I ended up doing it.

*Dependencies*

```
pip install cryptography PyJWT requests
```

*Code*

```py
import jwt, requests
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

GOOGLE_CERTS_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs'

def verify_id_token(id_token, audience):
    certs = requests.get(GOOGLE_CERTS_URI).json()

    for cert in certs.values():
        cert = str.encode(cert)
        cert_obj = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert, default_backend())
        pub_key = cert_obj.public_key()
        try:
            return jwt.decode(id_token, pub_key, algorithm='RS256',
                              audience=audience)
        except (jwt.exceptions.DecodeError,
                jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError) as e:
            pass
```

**EDIT**

I just realized [Google provides an example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library) in python for that, using their [oauth2client](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io) library.

Comment: fyi, oauth2client is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The Google API was recently ported to Python 3x and includes jwt verification. You can access it [here](https://github.com/enorvelle/GoogleApiPython3x).

As for your work around the only thing I'd highlight is the same point that Stefan made on the link you posted. That being the security vulnerability you're introducing as a result of having verify=False in your jwt decode call.

Comment: Thanks - I found the port, but am hoping to avoid using an unofficial library that is so bloated (for my purposes I only need a couple methods).  The only reason I was considering the google-api-python-client library at all was because I assumed it would have LTS.

Also, although I haven't tried it, it looks like verify kwarg in the workaround above can be True value since PyJWT now supports RS256.